# Qt: Philosophical UI Design Dilemma

Tags: qt

Our desktop application needs to run on Mac, Windows and Linux. That's why we chose Qt. Before, we had three separate code bases for those 3 platforms.

In the old implementation, we drew our own "window caption" with Close, Minimize, Maximize buttons. It looks the same in all three platforms.

This time around, I am not so sure. I thought of letting Qt use whatever's default caption and caption buttons for each platform, the rectangular "X", "_" windows buttons, the round buttons on the left hand side on the mac, and whatever goes with Linux/Ubuntu etc.

Is this a wise decision? One of the things pushing me there is that i'd have to write the resize code for the window class I'm writing, the dragging code, the button work and everything else that comes with writing your own windows caption.

I noticed that if I use this, " Qt::FramelessWindowHint" to remove the caption, i automatically lose my resizing grapple too. Is there a way around that? Also how would you go about implementing your own windows dragging code? (providing you knew the area you'd want to use as a "draggable caption". Seems like I need to catch the button down on that region, enter a drag mode, track the mouse movements and move the windows according to the deltas. Similar for resize. I've done that in other platforms before, but I wanted to ask if Qt has a mechanism that allows me to do that "out of the box"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I thought of letting QT use whatever's default caption and caption buttons for each platform

Please do that.  As a Mac user, few things are more confusing than "universal" interfaces that are supposed to look the same everywhere.  The Windows style interface is confusing.  The Mac Style interface is what I'm used to and what I want.

If you have to write (and maintain and support) less code, that's even better.

Just go with "native" as much as possible.  Write as little code as possible.

Comment: Hear hear!  Users of any given windowing system have a look and feel (and placement) that they're used to.  Any deviation from this makes them have to look harder to figure out how to perform the action they want, and thus makes the application feel harder to use.  And as this answer mentioned:  Less coding and support are always a good thing.

Comment: Thank you and other commentators. It makes sense to me and this is what I'll push to my bosses. I hope that our graphics artist who already designed a "custom caption" with special buttons won't scream to high heavens.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to let each app looks and feels native to the platform it runs on. The reason is simple: the user choose the specific platform for a reason. He or she likes how it looks and works.

There's of course exception to this. For full screen apps like games that don't use windows, dialogs, and much controls, cook your own and make it look the same across all supported platforms is OK and even desirable. But for normal windowed applications, better stick to the native UI guideline.

Answer (score 0):

I think that application should follow the UI Design of the operating system, this way the look and feel of the tool is similar to other operating system. Usually when application is created with exactly same UI in all three major platforms, it will not feel the same as other applications running in the OS.

For example Apple is quite strict with their own UI Design, and therefore mac users expect tool to work with particular way.

This also applies to shortcut keys, and that is probably the hardest part, because OS X, Linux and Windows have their own patterns in shortcut keys, and finding the proper combination is not always easy.